# Unable to read existing excel file

Tags: c#, epplus

Below is my code to read existing excel file:

```
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo("C:\\Excel\\SampleStockTakeExceptionReport.xlsx");
using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{
    var ws = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Content");
    ws.View.ShowGridLines = false;
    ws.Column(4).OutlineLevel = 1;
    ws.Column(4).Collapsed = true;
    ws.Column(5).OutlineLevel = 1;
    ws.Column(5).Collapsed = true;
    ws.OutLineSummaryRight = true;
    //Headers
    ws.Cells["B1"].Value = "Name";
    ws.Cells["C1"].Value = "Size";
    ws.Cells["D1"].Value = "Created";
    ws.Cells["E1"].Value = "Last modified";
    ws.Cells["B1:E1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Excel\\SampleStockTakeExceptionReport.xlsx");
}
```

While I run the code. It throws a runtime error.
Error.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: A worksheet with this name already exists in the workbook
at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheets.Add(String Name)
at Report.Form1.ExportToExcel1(DataTable Tbl, String ExcelFilePath) in C:\SMARTAG_PROJECT\SUREREACH\EXCEL\Report\Report\Form1.cs:line 43
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward, either:

- first check if the worksheet exists and only if it doesn't then execute your code
- just remove the existing worksheet if it exists and add it again with your values
- modify those values for the existing worksheet "Content"

---

Try something like this maybe:

```
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo("C:\\Excel\\SampleStockTakeExceptionReport.xlsx");
using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{
    //Check if worksheet with name "Content" exists and retrieve that instance or null if it doesn't exist       
    var ws = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Content");
    //If worksheet "Content" was not found, add it
    if (ws == null)
    {
       ws = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Content");
    }

    //Rest of code 
}
```

Comment: i want to read my file....its a report templates.. i want tloo edit my template and save in the same folder...

Comment: then the first option is the good one, just open the file check if the worksheet exists and if it exists edit it and save, otherwise add it, edit and save.

Comment: yeah...i have problem edit the file... where my code unable to edit.. since it throws error once he found the file...can you share any sample code. Thanks.

Comment: Based on the exception, it's not an issue of opening and reading the existing file, it's just that in the collection of Worksheets there, you already have a worksheet called "Content" so you need to override that one either by simply changing the data in it or by removing and adding it again.

Comment: I have a report template with worksheet. I just need to update few column. I shouldn't create new worksheet.

Comment: found it... instead of doing ws = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Content");.. i just do ws = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

Comment: @chinna_82 if you do it that way then it will crash if it doesn't exist, while my solution protects you from that because it uses FirstOrDefault and returns null if the worksheet doesn't exist.